# How to debug exwm with chemacs2?

Tags: spacemacs, exwm

I usually enter `s` `Return` in my terminal to start spacemacs.

After updating linux (in particular emacs 28.2 > 29.1) I got a blank screen instead.
I tried changing .xinitrc to `emacs --debug-init --daemon -f exwm-enable`, though without seeing any difference (still blank screen).

Any ideas where to start digging?

```sh
#.bashrc
alias s="WM=space startx"
alias d="WM=doom startx"
```

```sh
#.xinitrc
case $WM in
    space)
        emacs --daemon -f exwm-enable
        exec emacsclient -c;;
    doom)
          exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs with-profile doom;;
    \*)
          exec dbus-launch --exit-with-session emacs;;
esac
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `--daemon`?

Comment: Good catch, typo fixed

Comment: Should also be `---exit-with-session`.