# How to exclude emacs from updating in addition to pacman.conf

Tags: init-file

I'm ignoring emacs in `/etc/pacman.conf` and `emacs --version` indeed reports the same version (28.2) after system update. Yet I get a rather unpopular error `Error in spacemacs/user-config: void-function defvar-1`.

What else must I do in order to isolate emacs from upates?

Alas I'm unable to [properly init debug](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/79169/how-to-debug-exwm-with-chemacs2)